# "Could not parse the remainder" error

Tags: python, html, django, permissions, haml

I am trying to check if a specific group has permissions to modify another type of group

```
def can_write_object(self, obj):
    return (self.user.is_staff or
        self.userprofile.has_permission(obj, Permission.READ_WRITE))
```

I only want this button to be displayed if `policy.can_write_object()` function returns `true`

```
- if groups
    - for group in groups
        .btn-group
            - if policy.can_write_object(group)
                %a.btn.btn-mini{
                :data-toggle => "modal",
                :onclick => "$(\"#groupmodalcontainer\").load(\"{% url group group.id %}\");",
                }
                Modify Group
```

However, I keep getting this error

`TemplateSyntaxError`

`Could not parse the remainder: '(group)' from 'policy.can_write_object(group)'`

Comment: I dont know much about the `haml` syntax, but normally, you would do: `group|policy.can_write_object`

Comment: @karthikr thanks for the suggestion however, I get this error `Invalid filter: 'policy'`